# Meaning of “Make a declaration that”

Tags: meaning

There are two sentences below . I think both of them has same meaning . But i have some doubt about second one. Does it gives same meaning?  if you say yes please explain.

> The court declared that strike action was illegal.
>
> The court made a declaration that strike action was illegal.

Comment: They're equivalent, so you might as well stick to the "simplest is best / less is more" principle and go with the first version. But note that in practice ***ruled*** would be far more likely than ***declared*** here.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, they mean the same thing. There may be specialised situations or contexts in which they do not, but in general when one **declares** something, one is **making a declaration**. Absent special circumstances, they mean the same thing. Indeed, one might define *to declare* as *to make a declaration*.